# ANSIBLE access denied / failed to connect

Tags: ansible, access-denied

I faced with a problem when running my playbook example:

```yaml
- hosts: appserver
  become: true
  become_method: su 
  tasks:
  shell:
    /some_script/stop_application.ksh
  tags:
    - stop_app

- hosts: dbserver
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: oracle
  tasks:
  shell:
    /some_script/stop database_instance_name
  tags:
    - stop_db


- hosts: dbserver
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: oracle
  tasks:
  shell:
    /some_script/start database_instance_name
  tags:
    - start_db

- hosts: appserver
  become: true
  become_method: su 
  tasks:
  shell:
    /some_script/start_application.ksh
  tags:
    - start_app
```

I run the playbook like: `ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml  -i hosts -u my_user --ask-pass`

... and give my password to run.

The play runs fine, stops the application, stops database also, but for the start database section, I get `access denied / invalid user/password` error message.

I don't understand why I get "access denied" in the database start section, given that the stop database section the connection was good and the database has been stopped correctly.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27198695) and format it correctly. More specifically surround the code with code block markers and ideally set the language for highlighting hint (=> ```yaml). Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually amazed that this even works for other tasks since your "become_method" has an invalid value. [You are supposed to give a become plugin name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives), not a command. In your case it should be [`sesu`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become/sesu.html) and your potential parameters should go in `become_flags` which are `-H -S -n` by default as you will see in the linked documentation. Try again with a correct configuration and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: hello , my bad ,  become_method: su

Comment: @Zeitounator  hello , my bad , become_method was set to su . become_method: su

Comment: can anyone help ?

Comment: How have you tried to debug this?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen

Comment: @AulisRonkainen ,  i have no idea how it is possible this error .  i am looking for a workaround for the database start section . is it possible to tell to ansible instead of retry new connexion on the dbserver ( start_db section)  , to keep the same connexion ( stop_db) , to start the database ?

Comment: What happens when your run the same script manually as the oracle user on the target server ?

Comment: @Zeitounator all is ok when i fine when i run manually as oracle user .

Comment: Same question as AulisRonkainen: which steps did you take to debug this ? Running ansible in debug mode (`-vvv`) is the first thing you should do. Plesase do not add details in comments, edit your quesiton.